# Cannot connect to postgresql through sqlalchemy from different computer

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I think do not understand properly how does sqlalchemy works, I have tried to connect to postgresql running on some cloud server from my local computer:

```
db = create_engine('postgresql://ubuntu@172.23.160.212:5432/dbname')
```

but that causes the **error**:

```
Is the server running on host "172.23.160.212" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I have checked the port and host also exists.

I thought I should connect to the host using ssh first:

```
with SSHTunnelForwarder((172.23.160.212, 22), ssh_username='ubuntu', remote_bind_address=(127.0.0.1, 3306)) as server:
    db = create_engine('postgresql://postgres@127.0.0.1:5432/dbname')
```

But that did not help.

Comment: Can you open a telnet connection from your local pc to the cloud server on 5432?

Comment: I do not know what is telnet, but I usually connect to that server using ssh, it works fine. I can also accses database there

Comment: Is TCP connection enabled?. Have had trouble with similar issue in mssql

Comment: chances are, your pg_hba.conf is not configured for external connections or the firewall is blocking 5432. [telnet](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telnet) is a tool that can connect to **any** port, allowing you to to check if the port is available, w/o worrying about the actual protocol.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the problem partially,

If one opens ssh connection in bash (`ssh ubuntu@172.23.160.212 -L 5432:localhost:5432 -N -n -f`), then one can open db through python:

```
db = create_engine('postgresql://tissuemaps@localhost:5432/dbname')
```

If I understand correctly, the connection to postgres directly should also have worked, and why it does not, I do not know.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is TCP connection is not enabled and have to modify your pg_hba.conf file to allow the connection. Add lines in the config file to allow connection

```
host    all             all              0.0.0.0/0                       md5
host    all             all              ::/0                            md5
```

Apart from that you can also check `postgresql.conf` (/etc/postgresql/9.3/main/postgresql.conf) to check other postgres configs are what you expect like port number etc. Also add below line in config file to accept all the connections

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

You need to restart the postgres service for the changes to be picked up

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-connection.html

Comment: It had already the first line, I have added the second, but that id not help.

Comment: What errors you are getting? Are you able to connect using psql command line interface?

Comment: TO mad_ That is my question, I can reach out to psql when I am on the server, but if I do it from my computer, it even does not know what is psql, because I do not have it locally installed

Comment: You need a client tool to be installed locally to check the connection like pgAdmin or similar. Again are you getting the same error? It is definitely related to connectivity related so check firewalls, antivirus any tool that can block. Make changes as liberal as possible (for checking purpose).

Comment: in my case, I am able to connect remote PostgreSQL by dbeaver but not by my python script.